# Stop install4j from adding desktop shortcut via command line

Tags: java, install4j

I want to install a program in unattended mode via command line and not get a desktop shortcut.

This is the command I run:

`ZAP_2_7_0_windows.exe -q -varfile "C:\Program Files\ZAP_64_bit\.Npackd\customdir.varfile"`

And this is the `.varfile`:

`sys.installationDir=C\:\\Program Files\\ZAP_64_bit`

After installing the program, a desktop shortcut is created. How to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Condition expression" property of the "Add a desktop link" action in your project to

```
!context.isUnattended()
```

or, if you want to control it via the `.varfile`, set it to

```
!context.getBooleanVariable("preventDesktopLink")
```

and add the line

```
preventDesktopLink$Boolean=true
```

to the `.varfile`.